# awk syntax error in bash. Works fine in zsh

Tags: bash, shell, awk, zsh

I have written the following script that extracts a number from an rss file.

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -O selic https://conteudo.bcb.gov.br/api/feed/pt-br/PAINEL_INDICADORES/juros
line=$(grep 'dailyratevalue' selic)
index=$(awk -v var=$line 'BEGIN {print index(var, "dailyratevalue") }')
end=$((index+21))
echo $line | cut -c $index-$end | tail -c 4 | tr ',' '.' > selic
```

In zsh it works perfectly, but i need it to work in bash, too. I have tried running it on bash but i get the following error

```
awk: cmd. line:1: <content
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error
```

The error pattern `<content` comes from the line that is being fed as a parameter to awk, which makes no sense to me, since awk is just supposed to get me the position of the pattern i want.

What could this be?

Comment: Using `grep` to find a line number to pass to Awk is completely useless. Awk can match regular expressions just fine on its own, and the line number itself doesn't appear to add any intrinsic value here.

Comment: @RCS : Parameter passing works differently in zsh and bash. In your case, you could double-quote `"$line"`, but in general, it does not make much sense to construct a program which will work in zsh AND bash alike - there are too many differences.  Note also that if you want to run a script in bash or zsh, it is dangerous to put `/bin/sh` in the `#!` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DiegoTorresMilano's answer is probably better overall, but if you want to do it in bash, the main thing you need to do is double-quote your variable references. Without double-quotes around them, bash (and most shells other than zsh) splits variables into "words", and also expands anything that looks like a wildcard expression into a list of matching filenames. You almost never want this, so use double-quotes. In your case, there are two places they're needed: around `$line` here:

```
index=$(awk -v var="$line" 'BEGIN {print index(var, "dailyratevalue") }')
```

and here:

```
echo "$line" | cut -c $index-$end | tail -c 4 | tr ',' '.' > selic
```

Note that you don't need double-quotes around the `$( )` expressions, because they're on the right side of an assignment statement, and that isn't subject to word splitting and wildcard expansion. If they occurred elsewhere, you'd probably want double-quotes around them too.

BTW, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is really good at pointing out common mistakes like this, so I recommend running your scripts through it (even when they *seem* to be working correctly).

Answer (score 2):

`index=$(awk -v var="$line" 'BEGIN {print index(var, "dailyratevalue") }')`

should fix it.

Comment: That worked! But my output is not the desired one. Somehow the position of characters is different on bash and i ended up with junk instead of the number i need.

Comment: I am getting 249 for $index with both bash and zsh. What's yours?

Comment: 249, too. The characters outputted to the file are different, tho. I get the 3 chars immediately before the number i need.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` can do all of the extra steps. You can just

```
wget -qO - https://conteudo.bcb.gov.br/api/feed/pt-br/PAINEL_INDICADORES/juros | \
    awk -F '&[gl]t;' '/dailyratevalue/ {sub(",", ".", $25); print $25;}'
```

and obtain the value you want.

This is setting the FS and getting the field you want for the line that matches `dailyratevalue`.